# postfix doesn't work with IP as hostname

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, hostname

Using Ubuntu 14.04 x64

I had a working installation of Postfix which was handy for sending emails in my terminal, but I had an issue with an application that was critical for my workflow. In order for it to function correctly and I had to change my local machine's hostname to my network IP.

```
hostname `hostname -I`
```

https://superuser.com/a/571073/175088

Doing this fixed my work-critical application, but now postfix isn't working. I purged and re-installed postfix to pick up the new hostname, but attempting to start the postfix service now errors with the following message:

```
postfix: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: [IP-Redacted]
postfix: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: [IP-Redacted]
```

Is it possible to get postfix to work with an IP address as my hostname?

Comment: Why do you want to set it to an IP? There is no requirement that your `hostname` has to match `myhostname` of postfix. Set it to some `FQDN`

Comment: Really? It was still set to my original hostname, but it stopped working after I made the fix for my work program. That's when I purged and re-installed `postifx`. As far as just setting it to an `FQDN`. I don't actually have a hostname that is associated with my address on our internal DNS. Before it was just set to whatever Ubuntu put it as during installation.

Comment: I'm trying to debug this with telnet and postfix says `501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax` when I put an IP address where you'd normally put the host name.

Answer (score 0):

change myhostname to `ip-[IP-Redacted]`